# PyQt5 - Dynamically created widget doesn't show - No layout

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a widget that is an area where graphs will be created by the user, with the nodes being other widgets. The graph area code is roughly this:

```
class GraphArea(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName('GraphArea')
        self.parent = parent

        self.add_widget = None
```

There is a function called when the user adds a new node (I call them Entities):

```
def create_widget(self, add_info, x, y):
    self.add_widget = Entity(self, add_info[1], add_info[2], 1)
    self.add_widget.move(x, y)
```

Nothing special. Problem is, the created widget is invisible. It is there though, size and position, just not located in the GraphArea. When I tried to use a layout everything worked fine. Am I missing something obvious?

Note that when I pasted the "create" code in the `__init__` function, it worked properly. The problem seems to be when the UI has been initialized and trying to add the widget in the GraphArea at a random time.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I had to call the `.show()` function on the created widget. So something like this:

```
def create_widget(self, add_info, x, y):
    self.add_widget = Entity(self, add_info[1], add_info[2], 1)
    self.add_widget.move(x, y)
    self.add_widget.show()
```